# kineticjs attach group to mouse

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

In kineticJs, is it possible, after you have added a group to a layer, to bind the group to the users mouse pointer so that the user can move the group to where they would like it positioned? They would then click to drop it at that location.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it. The following code will be executed when the user wants to add the group to the layer:

```
layer.add(group);
layer.draw();
console.log(stage.getMousePosition());
stage.on('mousemove',
    function (){
        var mouse = stage.getMousePosition();
        group.setX(mouse.x);
        group.setY(mouse.y);
        layer.draw();
    });
stage.on('click',
    function(){
        stage.off('mousemove');
    });
```

Forgot to say. For the stage to get the mousemove event continuously, draw a rect on some layer and add it to the stage, even with opacity 0 because it won't work on empty areas.

Comment: Instead of adding event handler on a dummy stage object, you can directly add it to the group object that you have created.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the group property to draggable: true when you create the group, or set it to draggable after creation.

```
 <script>
  // make draggable on creation
   var group = new Kinetic.Group({
   draggable: true;
  });

  // make draggable after creation
  group.setDraggable(true);
 </script>
```

These also, you can turn off dragging after the group has been moved with the same method.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-a-group-with-kineticjs/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.